# NameError: name “x” is not defined

Tags: python, database, tkinter, python-3.7, sqlite3-python

```
> import tkinter
> import tkinter as tk
> from tkinter import ttk
> from tkinter import messagebox
> import sqlite3

# CREEAREA APLICATIEI + CONFIGURAREA ACESTEIA

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Raport 1.0d")

frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack()


# FUNCTIONALITATE BUTON_TRIMITERE

def trimitere_date():

   nume_tehnician = nume_tehnician_dropdown.get()
   schimb = schimb_dropdown.get()
   linia = linia_dropdown.get()
   descriere_problema = descriere_problema_entry.get()
   durata_interventie = durata_interventie_entry.get()
   rezolvare_problema = rezolvare_problema_entry.get()

      if not all ([nume_tehnician, schimb, linia, descriere_problema, durata_interventie, rezolvare_problema]):
    messagebox.showerror("Eroare", " Completati toate campurile!")
    return

      else:
    messagebox.showinfo("Succes", " Datele au fost introduse cu succes!")
    print("Nume tehnician: " + nume_tehnician)

# GOLESTE INPUT-URILE DUPA CE S-A TRIMIS RAPORTUL

   descriere_problema_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
   durata_interventie_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
   rezolvare_problema_entry.delete(0, tk.END)

   info_frame = tk.LabelFrame(frame, text="Informatii USER/probleme")
   info_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=20)

# TABEL PENTRU BAZA DE DATE

# DESCHIDEREA BAZEI DE DATE

   conn = sqlite3.connect('raport_zilnic.db')
   tabel = '''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS raport_data
    (Nume_tehnician TEXT, Schimb TEXT, Linia TEXT,
        Descriere_problema TEXT, Durata_interventie TEXT,
        Rezolvare_problema TEXT)
    '''

   conn.execute(tabel)

#INSERARE DATE IN TABEL
   data_insert_query = '''INSERT INTO raport_zilnic (Nume_tehnician, Schimb, Linia, Descriere_problema, Durata_interventie, Rezolvare_problema) 
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'''
    data_insert_tuple = (nume_tehnician, schimb, linia,
                    descriere_problmea, durata_interventie, rezolvare_problema )
   cursor = conn.cursor()
   cursor.execute(data_insert_query, data_insert_tuple)
   conn.commit()

# INCHIDEREA DATEI DE BAZA
   conn.close()

# CREEARE VARIABILELOR

   nume_tehnician_label = tk.Label(info_frame, text="Numele tehnician")
   nume_tehnician_dropdown = ttk.Combobox(info_frame, values=["nume1", "nume2", "nume3"])
   nume_tehnician_label.grid(row=0, column=0)
   nume_tehnician_dropdown.grid(row=1, column=0)

   schimb_label = tk.Label(info_frame, text="Schimbul")
   schimb_dropdown = ttk.Combobox(info_frame, values=["1", "2", "3"])
   schimb_label.grid(row=0, column=1)
   schimb_dropdown.grid(row=1, column=1)

   linia_label = tk.Label(info_frame, text="Linia")
   linia_dropdown = ttk.Combobox(info_frame, values=["LINIA1", "LINIA2", "LINIA3"])
   linia_label.grid(row=0, column=2)
   linia_dropdown.grid(row=1, column=2)

   descriere_problema_label = tk.Label(info_frame, text="Descrierea problemei")
   descriere_problema_label.grid(row=2, column=0)
   descriere_problema_entry = tk.Entry(info_frame)
   descriere_problema_entry.grid(row=3, column=0)

   durata_interventie_label = tk.Label(info_frame, text="Durata interventiei (in minute)")
   durata_interventie_label.grid(row=2, column=1)
   durata_interventie_entry = tk.Entry(info_frame)
   durata_interventie_entry.grid(row=3, column=1)

   rezolvare_problema_label = tk.Label(info_frame, text="Cum s-a rezolvat problema")
   rezolvare_problema_label.grid(row=2, column=2)
   rezolvare_problema_entry = tk.Entry(info_frame)
   rezolvare_problema_entry.grid(row=3, column=2)

   breakdown_checkbox = tk.Checkbutton(info_frame, text="BREAKDOWN (se bifeaza daca a fost BREAKDOWN)")
   breakdown_checkbox.grid(row=4, column=1)

# ARANJAMENTUL PE APLICATIE

   for widget in info_frame.winfo_children():
   widget.grid_configure(padx=10, pady=10)

# Goleste input-urile dupa ce s a trimis raportul

   descriere_problema_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
   durata_interventie_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
   rezolvare_problema_entry.delete(0, tk.END)

# BUTOANELE

   buton_trimitere = tkinter.Button(info_frame, text="Trimitere", fg="blue", command=trimitere_date)
   buton_trimitere.grid(row=5, column=1, sticky="news")

   buton_iesire = tkinter.Button(info_frame, fg="red", text="Iesire", command=root.quit)
   buton_iesire.grid(row=6, column=1, sticky="news")

# AFISAREA APLICATIEI

   root.mainloop()
```

ERROR:

```
C:\Users\sucimi2\Desktop\pythonProject3\Scripts\python.exe           C:\Users\sucimi2\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\main.py

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\sucimi2\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\main.py", line 61, in <module>

data_insert_tuple = (nume_tehnician, schimb, linia,

NameError: name 'nume_tehnician' is not defined

 

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Hello, I’m trying to make an app that retrieve infos and bring them to a data base, everything seems fine ( the GUI works, the data base is created and accessible ), but I’m getting the error I mentioned before (and I guess that will be the case for everyting from data_insert_tuple, not only that particularly one)

Does anybody know why this happen? I saw a tutorial on Youtube and for her, it worked without any further complications.

Comment: Please fix the indentation in your post. We can't tell which lines are inside the `trimitere_date` function. `nume_tehnician` is a local variable in the function, you can't use it outside the function.

Comment: Please fix the indentation, the code is unreadable. But given that `nume_tehnician=` line is first after def, I'm gonna say it's actually in the function and the line that breaks is not - please learn about scopes (`nume_tehnician` is a local variable to the function it is, it doesn't exist outside of it)